# How do you picture: $\Pr(B|A)$ shrunk down by $\Pr(A)$?

Tags: probability, visualization, bayes-theorem

4. Though understanding [these diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1638270/53259), I do not understand how to visualise [the following explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638252/53259):

> $\color{green}{[P1.]}$ Suppose you were to grab the edges of $A$ and stretch it out so it covers all of $\Omega$. $B$ stretches out with it. Now we ask, what proportion of $\Omega$ is covered by the intersection of $A$ and $B$? The answer is simply the proportion of $A$ covered by $B$. The proportional stretching of things doesn't change the proportion of $A$ covered by $B$ so this value is still $P(B|A)$.
>
> $\color{green}{[P2.]}$ But, $A$ isn't actually the whole universe. We have to shrink everything back down so it's all in the original size relative to $\Omega$. To do this, we shrink everything back down by a factor of $P(A)$ (the true size of $A$ within $\Omega$.

5. P1 and P2 appear tautological:  why are A and B are stretched to cover all of $\Omega$ in P1, but then are shrunk back to the original sizes in P2? What is the objective of the stretch and shrink?

> Now when we ask, what is the size of the the portion of $B$ that overlaps $A$ relative to the entire universe $\Omega$,
>
> $\color{green}{[P3.]}$ the answer is $P(B|A)$ shrunk down by $P(A)$
>
> which is $P(B|A)P(A)$.

6. How can you visualise, and can anyone please depict, $\color{green}{[P3.]}$?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a rectangle and label if $\Omega$.  Draw a smaller rectangle inside it, labeled $A$. For best effect, draw $A$ so it is to scale.   Likewise draw another rectangle inside $\Omega$ that overlaps $A$; label this $B$.   Shade in the overlapping region and label it $A\cap B$.

Now for measures $\mathsf P(\,\cdot\,)$, such as $\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B), \mathsf P(A\cap B)$, we are comparing the probability measure of those regions to  the entire space $\Omega$ (and thus $\mathsf P(\Omega)=1$).

For conditional measures, $\mathsf P(\,\cdot\mid A)$ we are comparing the probability measure of an area inside $A$ to the entire area of $A$.   As we are restricting our attention to $A$, then $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$ is only concerned about the portion of $B$ that overlaps $A$.   That is, the shaded region ($
A\cap B$).

The "stretch and shrink" is exactly this focus of attention.   Because we are comparing measures to $A$, we "rescale" so that $\mathsf P(A\mid A)=1,~ \mathsf P(B\mid A)=\mathsf P(B\cap A)\big/\mathsf P(A)$, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks. I will reread your answer, but did I already realise your first paragraph in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1638270/53259 (which I forgot to mention that I had prepared)?