# Why do we multiply probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

Let me take this question:

```
 The probability of raining tomorrow is 0.2. 
 Also, tomorrow I will toss a fair coin.
 What is the probability that tomorrow it rains and I get a head in the coin toss?
```

(Let's take that these two events are independent.)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B),$ because that's the definition of independent events.

Comment: But, why? Before, defining that definition, they must have had some intuition, or some way to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that we have an experiment with $M$  equiprobable outcomes $x_k$, $m$ of them considered favorable, and there is a second experiment with $N$ equiprobable outcomes $y_l$, whereby $n$ of them are considered favorable. The probabilities of success in these two experiments then are ${m\over M}$ and ${n\over N}$, respectively.

Calling these two experiments  *independent* means, by definition, that the $MN$ possible combined outcomes $(x_k,y_l)$ are considered equiprobable. Among these $MN$ combined outcomes there are $mn$ where both experiments turn out successfully. The probability that this happens is
$${mn\over MN}={m\over M}\cdot{n\over N}\ .$$

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Now I get it!

Comment: I have one more doubt. "Tossing a coin", can be divided into two equiprobable outcomes: head or tail. So in our case, getting a head is the only outcome considered favorable. Thus, giving it a probability(of success) of 1/2. But in the case of "will it rain tomorrow", how do you divide it into equiprobable outcomes?

Comment: Experience tells us that in two out of ten days with the present atmospheric conditions it will rain tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm.........Okay!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Half of the time that it rains, you'll get tails rather than heads (assuming independence and a fair coin, of course.) So it will only rain *and*  come up heads half as often as it rains. So we multiply the probability of rain by the probability of heads (one half).

Comment: What do you mean by 'time'?

Comment: Assuming you hypothetically repeated tomorrow over and over. (Or say you had a bunch of days with twenty percent chance of rain and you flipped a coin on each one.)

Comment: Now, I am confused by the meaning of "probability of raining tomorrow is 20%". What does it mean?

Comment: That is a philosophical question with no widely agreed-upon answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations

Comment: Start by looking at non-frequentist interpretations, such as Bayesian, Dempster-Shafer, et al.